# Bring up new Finder window on current desktop

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I've been using the <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut to open a new "Search my Mac" Finder window. However, the problem with this is that I recently turned on Sierra's new "prefer tabs when opening windows" option on. That means that if I have a Finder window open in Desktop #4 but am currently in Desktop #1, the "Search my Mac" window will open *in the Finder window in Desktop #4.* What's even more confusing is that the Finder window isn't brought to the front. It stays in Desktop #4 and no matter how many times you press the <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut, you'll be opening new tabs in that window with no visual cues whatsoever.

So is there any way to (force) open a new Finder window on the current desktop, almost like pressing <kbd>⊞</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> on Windows? I do this so often, that having to switch to the desktop with Finder open becomes burdensome.

Comment: Well, you can always drag the tab off of the tab bar…

Comment: Yeah, but that makes me have to go to that desktop, drag it out, and then go back to my original desktop. Really defeats the purpose of having a shortcut for that anyway! :-o

Comment: Try Command-Alt-N.

Comment: Funny, when the Finder isn't onscreen, it's Command-N, but when it is, it's Command-Alt-N. Thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted something slightly different (and I've updated my post to reflect that!)